# Spring Boot -> UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to activate security with Oauth2 + JWT, but I'm not succeeding. When I try to run the application in Spring Boot, it's returning this error: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager', I searched the internet and did not get something to help me.

I'm using Spring Boot: 2.1.0.RELEASE

follow my classes:

**Resource Server:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("us3r").password("pwd").roles("ROLE");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/categorias").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.stateless(true);
    }

}
```

**Authorization Server:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Component
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("mobile").secret("p@sswd").scopes("read", "write")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token").accessTokenValiditySeconds(20)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600 * 24);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter()).reuseRefreshTokens(false)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        accessTokenConverter.setSigningKey("algaworks");
        return accessTokenConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

}
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizationServerConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=authenticationManagerBean)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.algamoney.api.AlgamoneyApiApplication.main(AlgamoneyApiApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=authenticationManagerBean)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1646) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1205) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Without @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean") what you get ?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thanks for replying, removed the "@Qualifier (" authenticationManagerBean ")" but continues the same error

Comment: @TinyOS
Thanks for replying, removed the "@Qualifier (" authenticationManagerBean ")" but continues the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you need to wire an `AuthenticationManager` is that you are using the `password` grant flow:

```
.authorizedGrantTypes("password", ...
```

With the password grant flow, an OAuth2 client will give you its client credentials as well as the username/password of the user, and that user needs to be defined somewhere in your system. The ability to authenticate these users is exposed via an `AuthenticationManager` instance.

In an Authorization Server, there are two sets of users: the clients of the OAuth2 API and the end users of the application (the folks who want to log in).

The *clients* are defined in a class that extends `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`, which you have. You define them when you configure the `ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer`.

The *users* are defined in a class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, which you do *not* have. You can define them and expose the corresponding `AuthenticationManager` bean like this (**note that this is your main issue, but there are additional problems with your configuration, so read on**):

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
            User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("us3r")
                .password("pwd")
                .roles("USER")
                .build());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean()
        throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

That last method exposes the `AuthenticationManager` bean so that other Spring beans can depend on it (like your `AuthorizationServerConfig` bean).

Let's also do some cleanup of your other classes in order to reduce the noise, just in case you run into additional hurdles.

First, `AuthorizationServerConfig`. It's redundant to use `@Configuration` and `@Component`. You can just use `@Configuration`. Also, it may seem like extra work, but it's also helpful to use good whitespacing with Spring Security DSLs. Because of the fluent API, it's very powerful, but also very easy to make unreadable.

Also, when you go to production, this will feel a bit more natural, but you need to specify the hash mechanism that you are using for the client password. Since you aren't doing any hashing right now, that might feel a little weird, but [you'll need to prepend it with "{noop}"](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-default-password-encoder) for this sample to work.

And finally, 20 seconds is pretty short for an access token. I'd recommend at least a couple of minutes, though many [access tokens live for multiple hours](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-lifetime/). And if you want your user to have to re-login every day, then 24 hours is fine for a refresh token. Once the refresh token expires, the user will need to log in again with her credentials.

Based on your existing configuration, I would recommend (though stay tuned for some other problems with this setup):

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig
    extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
        throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("mobile")
                .secret("{noop}p@sswd")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(180)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600 * 24);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) 
        throws Exception {
        endpoints  
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
            .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = 
            new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        accessTokenConverter.setSigningKey("algaworks");
        return accessTokenConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }
}
```

Now, I noticed that the name of your client is `mobile`. **The modern recommendation for mobile clients is to use [PKCE](https://oauth.net/2/pkce/)**, which Spring Security does not yet support. Not knowing everything about your use case (seems like you are just trying to get things working right now), though, I will only mention that mobile apps are not good at keeping secrets, so you would need to select grant types that don't require the mobile app storing client secrets (and `password` most certainly *does* require client secrets).

Okay, second, `ResourceServerConfig`. We can remove `@EnableWebSecurity` because we have that on our new `SecurityConfig` class. Also, the Resource Server typically doesn't maintain a set of users (the Authorization Server has those), so we can remove the first `configure` method.

Based on your existing configuration, I'd recommend:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig
    extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/categorias").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
           .sessionManagement()
               .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
               .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) 
        throws Exception {
        resources.stateless(true);
    }
}
```

Just to be sure, I pasted this all into a local project in my IDE, started it up and was able to do the following:

```
curl --user "mobile:p@sswd" localhost:8080/oauth/token -dgrant_type=password -dusername=us3r -dpassword=pwd
```

Which came back with a token:

```
{ "access_token":"eyJh...",
  "token_type":"bearer",
  "refresh_token":"eyJh...", 
  "expires_in":199,
  "scope":"read write",
  "jti":"09855c19-7a71-4314-bf8f-eb74689d158c" }
```

Then I can do:

```
export set TOKEN="eyJh..."
```

If I then do:

```
curl localhost:8080/yo
```

I get a 401, but if I include the token:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" localhost:8080/yo
```

I get a 404!

Which, I realize is a bit anti-climatic, but hey, it shows that I got authenticated. :)

Now that I've said all of that, if you are *still* reading, then I'd also like to point out that, dependending on your needs, Spring Security 5.1 offers a simplified OAuth 2.0 API. It doesn't have an Authorization Server yet, but it does have JWT-based Resource Server and Client. I'd encourage you to [take a look at the feature matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix) to see if the newer stuff has the features that you need.

Answer (score -1):

Please  try with `authenticationManager` bean as below:

```
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
```

Comment: When I add the code snippet that passed me, I'm getting the following error:

The method authenticationManagerBean() is undefined for the type AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter